# Does multiple cross validations after a model selection make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Let be $M$ a model. Let also be $H_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ some hypothesis of $M$.

I have a dataset $\mathcal{D}$ and I want to run $K$-fold cross validation on $\mathcal{D}$ to pick the best model $H_j = \text{argmin}_{H_i} \ \ \varepsilon(H_i)$ where $\varepsilon$ denotes the RMSE.

Once I get $H_j$, I want to perform multiple $K$-fold cross validations on $\mathcal{D}$ to build a confidence intervals of this estimator.

I want to do this procedure with some models $M_k$ to select the best one based on the confidence intervals.

My question : Is this procedure meaningless ? Please be kind and provide answers with references.

Thanks !! Keep safe and stay home guys :)

Comment: I think it makes sense, in fact I have experimentally used this kind of approach myself a few times. However I don't have any reference to provide.

Comment: I used to do same because I feel unsatisfied with doing k-fold cross validation using k around 10. I think that setting it equal to 10 or 5 is too low. It may have sense to do so when the size of the data is too low but in my opinion the estimator may have a non-negligible variance. That's may be problem while doing model selection... Anyway, thanks.